# How can I insert value in mysql stored procedure after select statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedure and i appreciate if someone can help me!

I am trying to search for an email in table and if the email exists then it eill return the email and username, if it doesn't exist then it shall insert the email in the db, but the insert part is not working, below is my code but not sure what  i am doing wrong here - there are no errors or anything it is just don't insert to table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMnualUser(IN mail char(40))
BEGIN
DECLARE Mvar char(40);
SELECT user_email INTO Mvar 
from AppUsers WHERE user_email=mail;
IF @Mvar IS NULL
THEN
INSERT INTO AppUsers(user_email, username) 
values(mail,"username"); <=================
ELSE
SELECT user_email, username 
from AppUsers WHERE user_email=mail;
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mvar is not the same as Mvar

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMnualUser(IN mail char(40))
BEGIN
    SELECT user_email INTO @Mvar 
    from AppUsers WHERE user_email=mail;
    IF @Mvar IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO AppUsers(user_email, username) 
        values(mail,"username"); 
    ELSE
        SELECT user_email, username 
        from AppUsers WHERE user_email=mail;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE AppUsers (user_email varchar(255), username varchar(255))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMnualUser(IN mail char(40))
> BEGIN
>     SELECT user_email INTO @Mvar 
>     from AppUsers WHERE user_email=mail;
>     IF @Mvar IS NULL THEN
>         INSERT INTO AppUsers(user_email, username) 
>         values(mail,"username"); 
>     ELSE
>         SELECT user_email, username 
>         from AppUsers WHERE user_email=mail;
>     END IF;
> EN
> ```

> ```
> CALL InsertMnualUser("test@test.com")
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM AppUsers
> ```
>
> ```
> user_email    | username
> :------------ | :-------
> test@test.com | username
> ```

> ```
> CALL InsertMnualUser("test@test.com")
> ```
>
> ```
> user_email    | username
> :------------ | :-------
> test@test.com | username
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f71b467f2e5c386bdfece2e5ab46539f)*

Comment: Hi @nbk thank you so much for your reply and help - I have tried with the steps above (to include @Mvar but still same problem                                                                        ```mysql> call InsertMnualUser("example@hotmail.com");
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```  example@hotmail.com doesn't exist in my table records so it was supposed to insert the email but it didn't as shown from the query return

Comment: yes definitely your example is working from what I can see from fiddle example, but seems I have another problem on my terminal as it is not working here, thank you so much for your help, I will research more on what can cause this - I copied and pasted your example as is but doesn't insert for some reason

Comment: have you run the insert by hand? to see if it runs, also you add SET @a and @b with values and after running the procedure SELECT @a,@b , to see if it reaches the insert clause

Comment: Yes I have tried to insert by hand -without stored procedure - and it is working fine.
`
   -> IF @Mvar IS NULL THEN
    -> SET @a:="atest";  

  -> ELSE
    -> SET @b:="btest";
 
 mysql> call InsertMnualUser("example@example.com");
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @a,@b;
+------+-------+
| @a   | @b    |
+------+-------+
| NULL | btest |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure how to properly format this - but I can see the Select @a returns null which seems it is not reaching to the insert part

Comment: then it is in the if clause so the query runs, it can be that autocommit is not enabled. Please check it.